# ¿Cómo posicionar elementos en una misma linea con css?

Tags: html, css

estoy tratando de hacer esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero solo he logrado hacer esto, no logro bajar el "docente" justo debajo del nombre:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi html:

```css
.image--cover {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 20px;

  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center right;
}

.users{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #374457;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="users">
        <img src="https://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/10/10678-illustration-of-a-female-user-icon-pv.png" class="image--cover img-responsive">
        <span class="header-username">Lucia Sandoval</span>
        <span style="color: #929293; font-weight: 100">Docente</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo normalmente utilizo `display flex` para que te quede centrado verticalmente también.

```css
.image--cover {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 20px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center right;
}

.users{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #374457;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}


.container-username{
  
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="users">
        <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/10209884520134995/picture" class="image--cover img-responsive">
        <div class="container-username">
          <span class="header-username">Lucia Sandoval</span>
          <span style="color: #929293; font-weight: 100">Docente</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Notese que agregue un nuevo `div` con la clase `container-username` que agrupa el nombre y la palabra "Docente" para manipularlos a los dos con `display flex`

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta fue de gran ayuda!

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar el código y readaptarlo, algunas propiedades no tienen soporte en Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

El elemento  se visualiza *en línea* (por defecto tiene `display: inline`).

Puedes hacer que la imagen "flote" y añadir al segundo span `display: block`

```css
.image--cover {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin:  0 20px;
  float: left;
}

.users{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #374457;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.users span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="users">
        <img src="https://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/10/10678-illustration-of-a-female-user-icon-pv.png" class="image--cover img-responsive">
        <span class="header-username">Lucia Sandoval</span>
        <span style="color: #929293; font-weight: 100;">Docente</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

podes poner un contenedor extra para la info de usuario:

```css
.image--cover {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 20px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center right;
}
.users {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #374457;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* opcional: inline-block para que las cards vayan una al lado de la otra */
  display: block;
}
/* alinear la foto y la info */
.image--cover,
.user-info {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* mismo margin que la foto, inline-block para que quede a continuación */
.user-info {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* los span van block para quedar uno arriba del otro */
.user-info>span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="users">
    <img src="https://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/10/10678-illustration-of-a-female-user-icon-pv.png" class="image--cover img-responsive">
    <p class=user-info>
      <span class="header-username">Lucia Sandoval</span>
      <span style="color: #929293; font-weight: 100">Docente</span>
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es porque el elemento span es inline y si juntas 2 span se van a poner uno al lado del otro, agrégale "display: block" como estilo a tu elemento span y estará uno debajo del otro

Comment: utilizando el display:block lo baja, pero lo pone debajo de la imagen y no debajo del texto del nombre.